# babel not transforming arrow functions

Tags: angularjs, webpack, babeljs

Hi I'm working on a project built using AngularJS webpack and babel. Previous version of this was working and somehow something has changed in babel ( my guess), the arrow functions are not getting transformed while building the app. the 'env' preset is being used and plugins like "transform-object-rest-spread", "dynamic-import-node" are being used in .babelrc. The .babelrc in webpack is targeting the latest 3 versions of IE 9 and plugins used are

```
"transform-runtime", "transform-object-rest-spread", ["angularjs-annotate", {
"explicitOnly": true}]
```

If anyone has any idea how to fix this issue do let me know. Also I observed that the bundle files generated after running the build command are different from the previous version ( all the arrow functions are transformed to javascript functions). Thank!!